# Laravel whereHas query does not return relevant results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `belongstoMany` relation on my `Property` model.

```
public function amenities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Amenity', 'property_amenities', 'property_id', 'amenity_id')
        ->withPivot('status');
}
```

Then on my `post` method I have those params:

```
 $amenities = Array
        (
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 1
            [25] => 0
            [26] => 0
        )
```

Where the key is the amenity ID and the value is true or false (boolean).

Based on this information I am trying to query the relevant results so I build this query:

```
    $properties = Property::whereHas('amenities', function($query) use($amenities){
        foreach($amenities as $amenityID=>$status)
        {
            $query->where('property_amenities.id', $amenityID);
            $query->where('property_amenities.status', $status);
        }
    });
return $properties->get();
```

So in natural language I want all properties that have Metal Door (amenity_id 1 with status 1) and does not have Hone (amenity_id 2 with status 0) and so ....

In this moment my query returns all properties.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have built your query, it's looking like the following...

```
... 
where property_amenities.id = 1 
and property_amenities.status = 1
and property_amenities.id = 2
and property_amenities.status = 0
and property_amenities.id = 3
and property_amenities.status = 1
...
```

As you see, this doesn't make a lot of sense.  What I think you want it to do is something more like the following...

```
... 
where ( property_amenities.id = 1 and property_amenities.status = 1 )
or ( property_amenities.id = 2 and property_amenities.status = 0 )
or ( property_amenities.id = 3 and property_amenities.status = 1 )
...
```

And in order to accomplish this with the query builder...

```
$properties = Property::whereHas('amenities', function($query) use($amenities) {
    foreach ($amenities as $amenityID => $status) {
        $query->orWhere(function($q) use ($amenityID, $status) {
            $q
                ->where('property_amenities.id', $amenityID)
                ->where('property_amenities.status', $status);
        });
    }
});
```

I haven't tested this so I'm not sure if Laravel is smart enough to know that the first `orWhere` should actually be a where.  Before you start looping through amenities, you might have to add in a `->where(DB::raw(1), 1)` so that way Laravel will start building the query with `where 1 = 1` and then it can continue to do the rest of the `or`s.